# Getting error in Multilingual Dropdows Jquery Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, multilingual

I am working on Multilingual Dropdowns and I am getting an error in my jQuery Code.

Getting This error on (e.target)

TS2345: Argument of type 'Document' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Element | JQuery | Element[] | ((this: HTMLElement, index: number, element: HTMLElement) => boolean)'.
  Type 'Document' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': assignedSlot, attributes, classList, className, and 58 more.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#innerDiv");

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach the event to the body.

```
$('body').mouseup(...);
```

Comment: By using body error is not coming but As in code Div should be hidden (container.Hide() ) is not working. By clicking outside div is not closing or hiding

Comment: You have to debug. First check if everything is defined properly.
$('body').mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#innerDiv");
console.log(container);

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
console.log('check if the condition is properly set');
        container.hide();
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

by doing some change in code. My problem solved.

```
 $(document).on("mouseup", (e: JQueryEventObject) => {
      var container = $("#innerDiv");
      // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
      if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.hide();
      }
    });
```